# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run python script from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, child-process

I have my index.js:
In my index.js i have some code which calls the ML model that i have trained and gets the predicted y value for the x value that i am providing. Everytime i am running the code it says pandas not recognised and if i move that import to down line it actually shows the same statement for al modules though they are installed perfectly.

```
const express = require('express');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/predict', (req, res) => {
  // Get the input value from the query parameter
  const inputValue = parseFloat(371);

  // Spawn the Python script with the input value as an argument
  const childPython = spawn('/usr/bin/python3', ['index.py', inputValue.toString()]);

  // Capture the Python script's stdout
  childPython.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // Send the prediction back as a response
    res.send(`Prediction: ${data}`);
  });

  // Handle errors
  childPython.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`Error: ${data.toString()}`);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Also i have my index.py file which will perform some prediction and has to return the result back to index.js:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
# Load your dataset here
data = pd.read_csv("biomass-biogas.csv")

# Get the input value from the command-line argument
input_value = float(371)

# Your model and data processing code
X = data.drop(['BIOGAS'], axis=1)
y = data['BIOGAS']
feature_names = X.columns.tolist()
X = X.values 
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X, y)

# Use the input value to make a prediction
prediction = model.predict([[input_value]])

# Print the prediction
print(prediction[0])
```

The error says: Error:     import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I need to fix the above stated problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case of your Python environment at location `/usr/bin/python3` not having the library `pandas`. You'll need to install `pandas` in that python environment first.

Do the following:

1. `which python3` (shows the python directory your terminal will run python from)
2. If the path `/usr/bin/python3` shows up jump to step 4, otherwise do the following
3. `export PATH=/usr/bin/python3:$PATH` (sets the PATH variable to the `/usr/bin/python3`. This is a temporary fix... if you wish I can elaborate on a more permanent fix.)
4. `python3`
5. `pip install pandas`

You should be all set.